# Excel Sum of line 1 to 10 based on range number

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

How do I sum only based on range input?

[image]

Please help me above condition. Thank you very much.

Comment: The question is not clear. What does the "range" means here? Is it range as an object (i.e. does it define a row)? If so, go through INDIRECT function. Or is it the upper range of the value added up together(if so, use SUMIF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try the following solution.
Sample data is in Row C4 thru C10. B4 thru B10 are just Row number for clarity. They are not required. C2 is the range & F4 contains the sum of nth rows. n being the value in C2.

Put the following formula in F4

```
=IF(C2<=0,0,SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(C4)):INDIRECT("C"&ROW(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(C4)+C2-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW, you really god saver. thanks it solve my question.
I just don't understand how it work by using indirect function?

Comment: INDIRECT function can be used to get a Cell Reference specified by text. So formula =SUM(C2:C4)  & =SUM(C2:INDIRECT("C"&4)) result in same output. Above solution uses INDIRECT & ROW to manipulate the cell reference so that the SUM evaluates to the intended Rows as specified in the Range cell. More on INDIRECT function here on Office Support  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261